# Why are GCP Cloudbalancer Bucket returning a XML?

Tags: gcp-load-balancer

Recently, I created a bucket with an index.html and configured a loadbalancer http with bucket as backend.

I have been made this some times and it always has been worked, but in my last configuration it is returning an XML with this structure:

```xml
<ListBucketResult>
<Name>bucket_name</Name>
<Prefix/>
<Marker/>
<IsTruncated>false</IsTruncated>
<Contents>
<Key>01.png</Key>
<Generation>1587402672429680</Generation>
<MetaGeneration>1</MetaGeneration>
<LastModified>2020-04-20T17:11:12.429Z</LastModified>
<ETag>"0a3750e6fdb29fcd632e627e2fc34dde"</ETag>
<Size>211</Size>
</Contents>
...
```

I have been changed a lot of stuff and it doesn't seem work, what could be wrong in this configuration? some clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare the main page and the error page in google cloud
example by gsuit:

```
gsutil web set -m index.html -e index.html gs://www.example.com
```

[More information here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website#gsutil_2)